# Why use URL parameters over request body in API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, api-design

When making an API endpoint in Django Rest Framework for example, why would I ever use URL parameters to receive data rather than just putting everything in the request data?

I don't get the difference between the two.

Comment: You need to elaborate question properly with code / examples etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL parameters and body parameters server different purpose. The REST API grammar says

- **GET Method** is used when you want to retrieve data back and don't want to update any of the record in system. The GET method will not pass body parameter and hence whatever filter parameters passed to API will be through URL parameters.
- **POST/PUT Method** is used whenever you want to update your database. The value could be single parameter or even no input but you have to use POST/PUT method, if you are trying to update database record(s).

Comment: This answer is only explaining how it is done generally. It does not explain why it is done that way and what is the reasons it is done this way. What are the advantages of using GET requests with URL parameters over using POST with response body, aside from semantics? For example, I am not a fan of showing every parameter in the URL bar to my users, it generates meaningless and long URLs. With modern frameworks, I can send POST requests instead of GET requests for information I need to show in the page. Nothing is yelling at me "you did not update any data", in either of backend and frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Putting some query data in the URL allows the URL to store the "state" of your web application.

For  example a state can be "I queried how do I make cheese on stackoverflow", and the URL would be `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+do+make+cheese`.

This allows the web app to interact as expected with browser tools like Refresh, Go Back, etc. Without the state stored in the URL, refreshing the page might just take you back to the homepage, instead of showing you the same query results (the expected behaviour).

Additionally, you can copy & paste the URL. When someone clicks on it, they will be taken directly to that specific state.

On the other hand, you shouldn't use the URL to store/send sensitive data (as it can easily be seen, use the body instead), and you should make sure reloading an "action" URL won't execute the action again (like paying for a product twice!).